# php mysqli query not returning all the rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL table called **comments** that contains a column called `vz_comments` and basically I want to show all the comments related to the `character_id`. However my current query only shows 1 comment but when I put the statement into phpmyadmin it shows all the comments.

```
$comments_query = $conn->query("SELECT vz_comments FROM comments WHERE character_id='$comment_id'");

$comments_array = $comments_query->fetch_array();

echo $comments_array['vz_comments'];
```

Comment: You are only fetching one row. If you want all rows, use `fetch_all()`.

Comment: `$comments_array = $comments_query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

Answer (score 2):

[`fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) fetches **a single row** as an array of its columns (either numeric or associative, depending on the parameters. By default, `MYSQLI_BOTH` is used, retrieving an array with attributes of both styles.

To fetch the entire result in a single call, you should use [`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) instead.